# Chart.js plot live data

Tags: javascript, graph, websocket, chart.js, real-time

I am receiving live stocks data from a websocket and pushing the data into an array. I want to plot a line graph with live data.

```
let aaplArr = new Array(); // creating an empty array

let rowData = x.Data[0].RowData[4]; // this the data received from the websocket

aaplArr.push(rowData); // pushing data into array

let graphPoints = (arr) => {  
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          
          datasets: [{
             
              data: arr,
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                 
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
   
  });
```

I want  to call the graphPoints(aaplArr) function. I'm not getting the data on the graph. How do I get around this?

I have used HTML canvas for the graph and need to keep reloading the graph for every new value  in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create the chart again everytime which is inneficient and afaik not even possible, if I am correct chart.js throws an error that the canvas is already in use, to achieve what you want you need to create the chart once outside the function, store in in a variable and then in your `graphPoints` function you call `myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(...arr)` after that you can call the update method on chart.js like so: `mychart.update()` this will make chart.js update and render all the new values.